# Javascript - Update value of object inside Immutable Record

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects, immutability

I have an Immutable Javascript object (from the Immutable library) made like this

```
const myObj = Immutable.Record({
  id: 1,
  myObject: {
    firstValue: false,
    secondValue: false,
  },
});
```

I would like to update the firstValue property to *true* using the set method of the Immutable.Record class, but since this object is being used as a React state using Flux, I would like to do this in a single line, like this:

```
reduce(state, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case ActionTypes.CHANGE_VALUE:
            //The value to change is stored in action.value
            return state.set("myObject", //AddCodeHere);
    }
}
```

The *action.value* variable is mandatory, so I have to update that value using that variable.

How can I do that?

**EDIT**

I found the answer (a little bit complicated but it works). It uses one of ES6 latest things, the Object.fromEntries method.

```
return state.set(
          "myObject",
          Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(state.get("myObj")).map(([k, v]) =>
              k === action.value ? [k, !v] : [k, v]
            )
          )
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never using Flux but I think it maybe the same thing for Redux. Try to use this [Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns/)

```
return {
  ...state,
  myObject: {
    ...state.myObject,
    firstValue: true
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do what you said, but the thing is that I need to use that variable action.value to search the right key of the object. If I try to substitute firstValue with action.value, it says that I'm making an error. Same thing if I try to put like myObject[action.value]

Comment: Try this `[ ]` to update for the key:
```return {
  ...state,
  myObject: {
    ...state.myObject,
    [action.value]: true
  }
}```

Comment: That didn't work too, I'm sorry. Anyway, I found the answer looking here and there, I'll put it as an edit on my question. Thanks anyway for trying